# Temporary Admin Status for System Maintenance on User Account

Tags: sudo, privileges

I have a user account that I have given sudo privileges on my computer. I use this account for everyday use and system maintenance.

I know it isn't a good idea to give sudo permissions to an everyday account. Is there some way to get admin privileges temporarily when I want to do system maintenance, or should I really be using two user accounts?

Comment: I never heard of anyone saying that "it isn't a good idea to give sudo permissions to an everyday account" - while I can see your point, I think the security benefits are negligible... In fact, Ubuntu by default creates a single account during install which indeed has sudo privileges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is possible to change your sudo password so it is different from your login, but I don't know how much it will help. Maybe a better option would be to limit the types of commands you can use sudo with. I know that is possible, look into the `sudoers` file for a listing of what users can use sudo with which commands